# How to stop Flutter from making more ListView items when item count is not at the beginning

Tags: listview, flutter, pagination, future

I have a dynamic **ListView** that is supposed to retrieve paginated data from a REST API. The issue that I have is that since I don't know ahead of time how many items I am going to have, I cannot set the **itemCount** to any value. Hence, the **ListView** keeps generating **FutureBuilder** items that do not get fulfilled.

Is there a way to stop creating more items when I get to the end of the list, if the are no more pages available through the paginated API?

I use **FutureBuilder** to create the items as they become available.

Comment: `itemCount` is optional - in that case returning `null` from `itemBuilder` ends your list

Comment: Your answer is correct, thank you!

Comment: sure, your welcome